# R package dependecies are not available for own package

Tags: r, package, devtools

I'm currently working on creating my own R package by using the devtools Cheat sheet which is provided by the Rstudio team. Everything is working fine execept the automatic installation of dependency packages. My package depends on 6 packages which are available on CRAN.

This is how my DESCRIPTION file looks like:

```
Imports:
rmarkdown(>= 1.2),
birdring(>= 1.3),
knitr(>= 1.15.1),
fossil(>= 0.3.7),
psych(>= 1.6.9),
devtools(>= 1.12.0)
```

When I try to install my package (ringreport) on a computer without these packages I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: dependecies 'rmarkdown', 'birdring', 'knitr', 'fossil', 'psych', 'devtools' are not available for package 'ringreport'
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. In my understanding it should automatically download these packages from CRAN? When I install these packages by hand from CRAN the installation of my package works fine and I'm able to run my function. How do I solve this problem?